# how to display the given input field values in same visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

iam using  tag using components.is it possible to use any other components in visualforce . how find above solution .please give any idea.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :

```
<apex:page>
<script>
 function setVal(){
    var a=document.getElementById('{!$Component.myform.test}').value;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.myform.test2}').innerHTML = a;
 }
 </script>


<apex:form id="myform">
<apex:inputText id="test"  onchange = "setVal();"></apex:inputText>
<apex:outputText id="test2"  >
</apex:outputText>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:page >
<script>
function doRefresh(val){
var enteredValue=val;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="The Entered text is "+enteredValue;
}
</script>
<apex:form >
<apex:inputText onkeyup="doRefresh(this.value)" />
<p id="demo">The Entered text is </p>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This bunch of code will work as per your requirement and it is easy to understand.